# Track Linux kernel module usage over time

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'd like to keep track of which modules are loaded by the Linux kernel over a course of several weeks.

Q: How can I log each module load to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest you try [SystemTap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap).

This SystemTap script is a decent example, tracks process stop/start as well as kernel module load/delete.  Easy to remove the process stop/start aspect.

https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/procmod_watcher.stp